# Multiple Audio File Download using asp.net gridview in vb.net with JQuery

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I currently trying download multiple audio files from a asp.net gridview using JQuery. I currently have the files being downloaded as a zip file but I would like it if i could have all audio files being downloaded without being zipped, i.e just download the audio files as is to a specified folder. I program in VB.net 2010.

The way it programmed right now is with a asp.net gridview that displays the files with a checkbox to select which files to download but it downloads to a zip folder. I would want the same method but just get rid of the zipfolder.

If there is anyone out there that would assist me it would mean a lot to me.

Comment: Maybe you can add some code?

Comment: this is the javascript part:   function fnOpen(fl) {

              var flnm = fl
              //flnm = flnm.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "");

              flnm = flnm.replace(/\\/g, "");
              //    flnm = flnm.replace(/\r/g, "\\r");

              flnm = flnm + '.wav'


              //    flnm = flnm.replace(/\/g,"");
              window.open('DownloadRecording.aspx?FILENAME=' + flnm)
          }

Comment: Please include the code in the question's body. Also, could you add the section that shows how the files are downloaded to a zip folder?